# How Preview the Attachments(Documents) in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

**How Display the Bytearray format file in Browser instead of download**
Using JSinterop to display the file, .txt,.pdf,.jpeg,.mp4,.png type files are displayed in browser but .doc,.docx,.xlsx,.rtf files are not displaying 
JavaScript Code

```
 function openByteArray(DocumentName, ContentType, FileByte) 
    {
          var blob = new Blob([base64ToArrayBuffer(FileByte)], { type: ContentType });
          var link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
           var fileName = DocumentName;
           link.DocumentName = fileName;
           window.open(link);
        };
        function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
          var binaryString = window.atob(base64);
          var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
          var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
          for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
            var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
            bytes[i] = ascii;
          }
          return bytes;
        }
```

ASP.NET Core 3.0
Blazor`
(VS2019)

Comment: Whats your attempts so far?

Comment: Actually Documents saved in DB in byte array Format how preview that documents in blazor

Comment: Using following Javascript to preview that dispaly .txt, .pdf, .jpg,.png only rest of all format not display lie .tif,.xlsx,.doc,.docx,.zip    ' function openByteArray(DocumentName, ContentType, FileByte) {
      var blob = new Blob([base64ToArrayBuffer(FileByte)], { type: ContentType });
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
       var fileName = DocumentName;
       link.DocumentName = fileName;'
       window.open(link);

Comment: You should show your attempts. Questions which are just asking for code which show not efforts to solve yourself (aka "Write the code for me") are less likely to be answered. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to make a good question which are more likely to be answered by others

Comment: @Tseng update the question check now